# MoqRT Error - Unhandled Exception while Creating MoqRT.Baked.dll

Tags: sqlite, testing, frameworks, windows-runtime, mocking

I am using VS2013 community edition, SQLite and created Test project using MSTestFramework where I am referring MoqRT framework for creating mock objects.

But while creating mock objects I am getting an Error as follows,

```
Unhandled baking exception:  --> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': This operation is only valid in the context of an application container. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007109A)
   at SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String filename, IntPtr& db)
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String databasePath)
   at MoqRT.Baking.BakingController.GetDatabase()
   at MoqRT.Baking.BakingController..ctor(String testAssembly, String appxPath, String bakingPath)
   at MoqRT.MoqRTRuntime.InitializeBaking(String testAssembly, String appxPath, String bakingPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at MoqRT.Baking.BakingWorkItem.Run(BakingContext context) in d:\Kierron Matte\Projects\Mercury\R & D\Unit Testing\MoqRT-master\MoqRT.Baker\Controller\BakingWorkItem.cs:line 35
   at MoqRT.Baking.BakingPoke.RunWorkItem(BakingController owner, WorkItem item) in d:\Kierron Matte\Projects\Mercury\R & D\Unit Testing\MoqRT-master\MoqRT.Baker\Controller\BakingPoke.cs:line 36
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at MoqRT.Baking.IBakingPoke.RunWorkItem(BakingController owner, WorkItem item)
   at MoqRT.Baking.BakingRunner.ThreadEntryPoint() in d:\Kierron Matte\Projects\Mercury\R & D\Unit Testing\MoqRT-master\MoqRT.Baker\Controller\BakingRunner.cs:line 55
```

I had referred the project and steps from GitHub "/mbrit/moqrt"
but not able to create MoqRT.Baked.dll.

I have referred the following files in my test project,

1. MoqRT.MetroStyle.dll
2. MoqRT.MetroStyle.pdb
3. MoqRT.MetroStyle.pri

I have also added the image for your reference.
Thanks in advance.
[Unhandled Exception while Creating MoqRT.Baked.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOION.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by removing additional SQLite (For Windows RunTime) reference from my Test Project which was not similar as used by MoqRT version (SQLite3.dll).